# Join four tables with MySql

Tags: mysql

I have four tables, with their respective 'arguments'

```
Movie(name, movie_ID,....)
Ticket(movie_ID, person_ID, ....)
Person(person_DNI, person_ID,....)
Date(person_DNI, Segment)
```

I need form the following table,

```
person_ID | person_DNI | movie_ID | Segment
```

So, for this I join the first two table (movie and ticket) and then the following two table(date and person)

```
SELECT person_ID, movie_ID
FROM `Movie` A JOIN `Ticket` B ON A.movie_ID = B.movie_ID 


SELECT person_DNI, B.person_ID, A.segment
FROM Date A 
LEFT JOIN Person B ON A.person_dni=B.person_DNI
```

But now, how can join this two 'now' tables?

My idea is join on person_ID from Ticket and Person

Comment: What is `person_DNI` ? and what is `Date` table? You need to explain the cardinality of the table to see which order we made the JOINS. Is a `DATE` have several persons or is a person several dates

Comment: and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT D.person_DNI,  D.Segment, P.person_ID, T.movie_ID
 FROM Date D
 JOIN Person P 
   ON D.person_DNI = P.person_DNI
 JOIN Ticket T
   ON P.person_ID = T.person_ID 

 -- Because you dont use anything from Movie like Movie.name 
 -- you dont really need join Movie to get movie_id
 JOIN Movie M
   ON T.movie_ID = M.movie_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't detailed the significance of each column, my answer performs inner joins without attention to order.

Preferably, you can join multiple tables in a single query:

```sql
SELECT person_ID, t.person_ID, m.movie_ID, Segment
FROM Person p
JOIN Ticket t ON t.person_ID = p.person_ID
JOIN Movie m ON m.movie_ID = t.movie_ID
JOIN Date d ON d.person_DNI = p.person_DNI
```

Or (not as good), you can query temporary tables by nesting queries:

```sql
SELECT t1.person_ID, person_DNI, movie_ID, Segment
FROM (
    SELECT person_ID, movie_ID
    FROM `Movie` A JOIN `Ticket` B ON A.movie_ID = B.movie_ID 
) t1 
JOIN (
    SELECT person_DNI, B.person_ID, A.segment
    FROM Date A 
    LEFT JOIN Person B ON A.person_dni = B.person_DNI
) t2
ON t1.person_ID = t2.person_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Natural Join in MySQL:

```
SELECT person_ID , person_DNI , movie_ID , Segment
FROM (((Date NATURAL JOIN Person) NATURAL JOIN Ticket ) NATURAL JOIN Movie)
```

For more informations, check out this link: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-natural-join.php

I hope this helps.